# GTK+ installation

Tags: linux, gtk

I am using ubuntu 12.10. I have CODE:Blocks IDE.
I want to use gtk+ but when i create a project and build it it says it cannot find gtk.h file.

I downloaded gtk+, glib, pango, gdk-pixbuf and atk by writing

```
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gtk+, 
git clone git://git.gnome.org/glib

...
```

then i unzipped all libraries. every thing was fine unti here.

To install gtk+ i write "./configure --prefix=/opt/gtk"
it starts processing, most of the process goes OK, but then it comes with an error

```
...
checking for some Win32 platform... no
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for BASE_DEPENDENCIES... no
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.33.1    atk >= 2.5.3    pango >= 1.30.0    cairo >= 1.10.0    cairo-gobject >= 1.10.0    gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.26.0) were not met:
No package 'glib-2.0' found
No package 'atk' found
No package 'pango' found
No package 'cairo' found
No package 'cairo-gobject' found
No package 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BASE_DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS
and BASE_DEPENDENCIES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I tried to install other libraries by writing ./configure in their directory. But it could not file configure file.

I set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` but it does not work anyway

How can I install it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the `git clone` step. This would be required only if you wanted to rebuild GTK+.

What you want is the development packages of your Linux distro. Search in your packages for something like `libgtk*-dev`, and install it. This will install the headers you need and all the dependencies required. Furthermore, `pkg-config` won't require any hint to find the `.pc` files that describe how to build and link applications against those libraries, so no need for configuring `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

Answer (score 11):

You should use : apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev

Comment: It'd probably be good to say why instead of just giving unexplained and incomplete directions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jhbuild as suggested on gnome.org
It installs dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev

before installing GTK

Comment: Welcom to SO, you're answering on a nearly 8 year old question. The question is long outdated as Ubuntu 12.10 is already ancient and msotlikely not be used by the OP or anybody else anymore. As such your answer is unecessary despite the fact not fullfilling requirements to be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

I already pass through this. It is because the IDE (in your case Code::Bloks) is not set for compile the gtk library. You need to compile it manually in the terminal:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` -o nameOfYourFile nameOfYoutFile.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

afther you can run it both in codeblock or in the terminal.